# Is it possible to assign a style to selected cells with a shortcut key in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, styles

I'm working on a job where they assign specific styles to cells to indicate meaning about that cell.

Presently, we select the cells, and then do things like:

- Assign a foreground color using the toolbar.
- Assign a background color using the toolbar.
- Assign Bold, Italics, Underline using their keyboard shortcuts.

I know I can record a VBA macro, and then modify it to assign all the desired styles and I guess assign the macro to a shortcut key, but I was just wondering if there was any sort of built-in functionality in Excel I could more easily setup and use to accomplish the same thing faster than writing / recording a macro to achieve the cell styling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom cell styles Cell Styles,

See image below.

[image]

There are some default styles, or you can simply create your own to suit your needs.

The custom created cell styles are only for that specific workbook though only, not all of Excel,

This does mean any user can see & use them, great if sharing etc.

Comment: Can you use a shortcut key to assign the styles?  Also does it work with an older version of excel, like 2010?  (It's probably in there, just hidden)

Comment: for a short cut key I'm assuming you will have to go down the vba route, and yes they work in 2010, in fact you get better viability of them in 2010 i think.

Comment: If you want to avoid VBA, and you're only applying styles, you could apply it once then press CTRL + Y to redo the action. If you highlight an already formatted cell and double click the format painter, you can apply the style elsewhere with a single click. 

There are also plenty of add-ins out there that might save you some time and clicks: https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/font-fill-color-style-excel-add-in/

Comment: @PFitz I'm not afraid of VBA, it just seems like too much trouble to do something so simple...

Answer (score 1):

I used the above Alt-H,J method, but saved the sequence to a macro key.  I use MultiKeyboard Macros by Mediachance, so this was perfect.

One key on my macro keyboard runs this sequence:

```
Alt-H
J
HOME
RIGHT
RIGHT
ENTER
```

NOTE: I use Excel with the "After pressing Enter, move selection" checkbox un-checked in Options/Advanced.
Most people probably need to add a compensating movement command at the top of that list to return the cursor to the edited cell before running the rest of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

This question is over 4 years old, but I found a way to apply cell styles using keyboard.

- Press (and release) Alt
- Press H, J
- Select the desired style using cursor keys
- Press Enter